# Firebase storage add file reference to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a form upload working to upload data to my Firestore db as well as upload an image to my firebase storage.

Individually I can do both, however outside of storing the exact URL of the uploaded image I can't seem to figure out how to programatically store the Reference to the image in my firestore.

In the console I can set the type to "Reference"
[image]

But whatever I try programatically doesn't work:

Post image upload:

```
const url = await storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
let imageRef = storage.ref().child(`test/${this.imageData.filename}`).ref
// let imageRef = storageRef.snapshot.ref
// let imageRef = storage.ref(`test/${this.imageData.name}`)

const docRef = await testImagesCollection.add({
   thumbnail: imageRef,
   dateCreated: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})

alert("upload succeeded", docRef.id)
```

I usually end up with: `FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Reference object (found in field thumbnail)`

If I have to I'll just store the URL but I rather not do that, if the console allows me to set a reference I should be able to do it programatically as well?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firestore reference types only work with references to other documents represented as [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) objects.  They don't work with references to objects in Cloud Storage.  If you want to store a reference to an object in Cloud Storage, you should either store the path to the file in the bucket (as a string, not as a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) object), or a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) (whichever is more convenient for you).

If you have a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) object, you can get a string path to it with its [fullPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#fullpath) property.

Comment: That's what it seems to be programmatically, but then what is the Reference type in the console for?

Comment: As I said in my answer: "Firestore reference types only work with references to other documents represented as DocumentReference objects."  A Cloud Storage object is not a Firestore document.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand why it works via the console. When done via console, I can access that Storage reference in code and get the `.path` on it then get the download url. But thank you for the response, I guess I'll just store the path.

Comment: @LanFeusT "what is the Reference type in the console for". The Reference type is indeed a "strange beast"... you will find more details in this #AskFirebase video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elg2zDVIcLo&t=274s